# SQL Server stored procedure parameters data type error

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

The following stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 was throwing an error

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UpdateCPA]    ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pdateCPA_INT]
    @CPAColumn_Name nvarchar(100), @value Int, @RecordNum nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --declare @CPAColumn_Name nvarchar(100) = 'UsrsID'
    --declare @value Int = 3575
    --declare @RecordNum int = 1

    declare @thedate smalldatetime
    set @thedate = GETDATE()
    --select @thedate as NOW

    declare @cmd nvarchar(max)

    set @cmd = 'Update tblTimeCPAReport 
    set ' + @CPAColumn_Name + ' = '+@value+' 
    set ReportLastUpdate = ' + @thedate + '
    where RecordNum='+@RecordNum

    exec sp_executesql @cmd
    select @cmd
END
```

It's throwing this error

> *Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Update
>   tblTimeCPAReport set UsrsID = ' to data type int.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `cast()` the `int` parameter -- `cast(@value as nvarchar(100))`:

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UpdateCPA]    ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pdateCPA_INT]
    @CPAColumn_Name nvarchar(100), @value Int, @RecordNum nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --declare @CPAColumn_Name nvarchar(100) = 'UsrsID'
    --declare @value Int = 3575
    --declare @RecordNum int = 1

    declare @thedate smalldatetime
    set @thedate = GETDATE()
    --select @thedate as NOW

    declare @cmd nvarchar(max)

    set @cmd = 'Update tblTimeCPAReport 
    set ' + @CPAColumn_Name + ' = '''+cast(@value as nvarchar(100))+''' 
       ,  ReportLastUpdate = ''' + convert(nvarchar(25), @thedate, 120) + '''
    where RecordNum='''+@RecordNum+''''

    exec sp_executesql @cmd
    select @cmd
END
```

Since your `@cmd` is  the datatype `nvarchar(max)` all of the parameters being used need to be similar, including:

```
@value  -- use cast(@value as nvarchar(100))
@thedate --- use convert(nvarchar(25), @thedate, 120)
```

Comment: ok so i actually not having to set different SP for each Datatype , as a sentence of text  it findes out for itself acording to the value type and its database container , makes sure i didnt "break the rules" and that's all it needs ...

Comment: @LoneXcoder you can pass in the datatype in the correct format, but when you add it to your `@cmd` it will need to be the same datatype as that variable otherwise it will be incompatible

Comment: I hope you dont mind it still throws an error , although i have solved much more complex isues then this simple one i couldnt put my finger on where it went wrong i will update my question please follow

Comment: @LoneXcoder see my edit, I think I found your error. You had two `set` statements you only need one with a comma between the fields

Comment: mr' blue .. i have aventually ... finally used YOUR ANSWER ! , sorry to let you down didn't have the time or patiance to try with you ..and wait, now you have the 'reward ' i thank you from the buttom of my brains that was close to explode !! (:

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the server sees a `+`, it examines the types on both sides, and if they're different, it has to perform a conversion.

For `' = '+@value+'`, on the left we have a string (`nvarchar(max)`) on an the right an `int`. It decides to convert the string to an `int`.

To prevent this, convert the `int` to a string yourself: `' = '+CONVERT(nvarchar(10),@value)+'`

Answer (score 1):

1) You should cast @value to a varchar

2) That second “set” will cause an error, propt syntax is `SET <col> = <values> [, <col> = Value>, …]`

3) Cast @thedate as a varchar, and enclose it in quotes

4) If @Recordnum is a string, put quotes around it as well, otherwise it’s good

Using all the above, the following:

```
set @cmd = 'Update tblTimeCPAReport 
set ' + @CPAColumn_Name + ' = ''' + cast(@value as varchar(10)) + '''
set ReportLastUpdate = ''' + convert(varchar(50), @thedate, 109) + '''
where RecordNum = ''' + @RecordNum + ''''
```

should produce a string like:

```
Update tblTimeCPAReport 
 set <CPAColumn_Name> = <@value>
  ,ReportLastUpdate = '<@thedate>'
 where RecordNum = '<@RecordNum>'
```

(Factor out the quotes around @RecordNum if it is contains a numeric value)